# Использование функции при нажатии кнопки python PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Написал пример приложения на PyQT5, тестирую использования функции при нажатии кнопки, но мне надо, чтобы основная функции использовала другие функции и выдала расчет

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize    

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 200))    
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt button example - pythonprogramminglanguage.com") 

        pybutton = QPushButton('Click me', self)
        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod)
        pybutton.resize(100,32)
        pybutton.move(50, 50)  

    def calc():
        return 10 + 20      

    def clickMethod(self):
        print('Clicked Pyqt button.')
        calc()  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Но выдает ошибку

```
  File "C:\Users\deriabin_ns\SecondProgram.py", line 24, in clickMethod
    calc()
NameError: name 'calc' is not defined
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Функции внутри классов должны иметь параметр self либо быть
   статичными.
2. Чтобы обратиться к функции класса нужно написать `объекткласса.имяфункции`
3. Вы можете вынести свою функцию из класса

Исправленный код

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize


def calc():
    return 10 + 20


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 200))
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt button example - pythonprogramminglanguage.com")

        pybutton = QPushButton('Click me', self)
        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod)
        pybutton.resize(100, 32)
        pybutton.move(50, 50)

    def clickMethod(self):
        print('Clicked Pyqt button.')
        calc()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!